# While Try Except Python

Tags: python, windows, while-loop, try-except

what i want is if the user enter the email address in a wrong format, it should trigger the except, print the error and head back to try.

```
x = True
while x==True:
    try:
        email = (input("Enter Email: "))
        if re.fullmatch(regex,email):
        x = False
    except:
        print("Email is inValid. Please type in this format: email@email.com")
```

the code works fine if you correctly input the email, but when you do it wrong, it will head back to try without triggering the except

Comment: What sort of error do you expect to be excepted?

Comment: regex = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z]+(\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+')
i have this regex and i want to check the input with this. what sort of error should i expect ? Value ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not raise any exception. Just use a good old "if/else" statement instead, as follows:

```
x = True
while x==True:
    email = (input("Enter Email: "))
    if re.fullmatch(regex,email):
        x = False
    else:
        print("Email is inValid. Please type in this format: email@email.com")
```

And it could be a little shorter, as follows:

```
while True:
    email = input("Enter Email: ")
    if re.fullmatch(regex, email):
        break
    print("Email is inValid. Please type in this format: email@email.com")
```

Comment: Yea it worked well. it seems that it was the basic understanding of try except i was struggling with. thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `assert` statement if you prefer the flow of raising and catching an exception:

```
while True:
    try:
        email = input("Enter Email: ")
        assert re.fullmatch(regex, email)
        break
    except AssertionError:
        print("Email is inValid. Please type in this format: email@email.com")
```